# play billing v6 registering subscription purchase under wrong user

Tags: android, google-play, subscription, play-billing-library

When attempting to purchase a subscription on a device with multiple accounts, the purchase is being registered in an account other than the active one in the Play Store app. Despite recognizing the signature in both accounts, the app does not display the subscription because it was registered in the other account. Switching the active account on the Play Store app allows the subscription to be visible on the subscription details page. When testing in debug mode, the subscription appears correctly, but when publishing the app and running in release mode, the problem occurs. Is this an issue caused by a Google update or am I making a mistake in my code?